# Create or increment item in collection?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am using using Underscore.js. Say I have the following JavaScript array:

```
var birds = [
  { name: 'pigeon', count: 2 },
  { name: 'swallow', count: 6 }
];
```

And I would like to take an arbitrary bird name. If it's already in the array, I'd like to increment the count by 1. If it isn't, I'd like to add it, with a count of 1. What is the best way to do this with Underscore?

Currently I'm doing:

```
var mybird = 'swan';
var bird_present = _.find(birds, function(b) { return b.name === mybird) });
if (!bird_present) {
   birds.append({ name: mybird, count: 1});
} else { 
  _.each(birds, function(b){
    if (b.name === mybird) { 
       b.count += 1;
    }
  });
}
```

But the use of both .find and .each feels messy. Is there a more compact way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_.find()` returns a reference to the "bird" object in your array. Through that reference you can directly manipulate the object:

```
var mybird = 'swallow';

var bird = _.find(birds, function(b) { return b.name === mybird; });

if (!bird) {
    birds.push({ name: mybird, count: 1 });
} else {
    // updating our reference to the bird object in "birds" arr
    bird.count += 1;
}
```

You also had a syntax error on your `_.find()` line. And the correct method for appending to an array is `.push()`.

With these tweaks I feel your code is already both succinct and readable. 
​

**http://jsfiddle.net/Sf4xc/1/**

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise it returned a reference.